# Native ipv4 to (unknown) native ipv6

Tags: ipv6

I am currently doing research on the following:

Let's say company A has a native IPv4 network and their firewall is IPv4 only so dual stack is not an option.

Company B is a company in China and they are IPv6 only.
Company B is hosting a website ipv6address.companyB.cn.
Company A & B are 2 different companies and don't have any information about eachother.

How can company A visit the website from company B?

In other words:

Is there a solution, besides dual stack, for native IPv4 to reach the IPv6 internet.

As far as I found out is that their is no “dynamic” solution to enable IPv4 Clients to communicate to IPv6 Servers, only static.

Meaning:

For a native v4 client to reach native v6 servers, all that is available at the moment is stateless NAT46, and this requires static DNS entries as well.

Therefore my question here, hopefully someone had a similar situation and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic? It's clear that without some router that speaks both protocols, there is no solution.

Comment: I mean that what I found out is that for a native v4 client to reach native v6 servers, all that is available at the moment is stateless NAT46, and this requires static DNS entries as well. So meaning, you need to know the IPv6 address of the server to make a mapping.

I am looking for a solution that companyA can put after their current edge router. Like you say, company A will require a router that can support IPv4/IPv6. But also a device that can make the translation from IPv4 to IPv6 and this is where I am struggling with. Does that make my question more clear?

Comment: Company A should replace the antique firewall. It probably isn't sufficient for 21st century workloads anyway.

Comment: Yes, that would be the easy solution. But I'm looking for an alternative so that company A does not need to make a whole new network plan, new firewall rules, not to mention the cost of a new firewall.

Is there no solution possible with some kind of redirect server?
A device that can resolve AAAA records and resolve it to an A record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not need to dual-stack the entire LAN, but having at least *one* dual-stacked system is **unavoidable**, because IPv4-only networks cannot access IPv6-only networks without *some* dual-stacked relay in between. (However, that system might be a cloud server, not necessarily located in your own network.)

Once you have that, there are several options, but these are the most likely:

If you need this to work company-wide and for *all* IPv6 destinations:

- Search for (I believe that's the name) stateful **NAT46**, which is similar to NAT64 and consists of 1) a DNS server that provides fake A records according to real AAAA records, and 2) a relay server that does the actual routing/translation (receives IPv4 packets meant for these fake addresses, sends out IPv6 packets to the real address). The relay obviously needs both IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity.

  (NAT46 can be automatic just as NAT64 is, it's only a matter of finding software such as DNS servers which implements it...)

If you need this just on a few client hosts, but for all destinations:

- Set up a **VPN server** that provides IPv6 access. Individual hosts connected to the VPN server gain IPv6 access through it, without affecting the rest of the corporate network. IPv4 can still go direct.
- Or use a traditional "protocol 41" tunnel, such as the ones provided by Hurricane Electric.

If you need this just on a few client hosts, for all websites, but only websites (HTTP/HTTPS):

- Set up a basic **HTTP proxy server** (e.g. Squid) and obtain IPv6 connectivity *just for that server*. Users who require access to IPv6-only websites can set their browsers to use the dual-stacked proxy.
- A similar solution that's not limited to HTTP(S) would be to provide a SOCKS5 proxy, or even **SSH "dynamic tunneling"** which provides instant SOCKS-compatible proxying. In all cases, the proxy itself needs IPv6 connectivity.

If you need this company-wide, but for just one website or two:

- For HTTP, set up a **reverse proxy** (using nginx/Apache/HAproxy) that accepts requests at `http://proxyhost` and forwards them to the real IPv6 server. The same reverse proxy can handle several vhosts.
- For non-HTTP, find something similar to OpenBSD's *relayd*.

Finally, the relay server itself can get its IPv6 connectivity using the same methods (VPN or proto41 tunnel) as in the "individual hosts" section above.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed awnser grawity, I will research and test http proxy with ipv6 connectivity.

The first option you told me would have been the most ideal.

But I found out that there are way too many issues when doing DNS46 for NAT46 (check RFC-4966), so usually NAT46 is done in a stateless way for known destination addresses.
With static entries in the DNS.

Comment: Keep in mind that several of these transition approaches would also likely require replacing that ancient firewall.

Comment: Most of them (VPN, Squid, SSH tunnel) actually wouldn't need that, as long as the company can get one IPv6-capable system somewhere else. Workstations would only make IPv4 connections to the proxy.